# Error executing SELECT * FROM "migrations_state" WHERE "key" = ?: No value specified for parameter 1. db-migrate

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, dbmigrate

[Container] 2021/09/30 02:06:18 Running command db-migrate up

Initializing driver...
creating table: migrations_state
Error executing SELECT * FROM "migrations_state" WHERE "key" = ?: No value specified for parameter 1.

[ERROR] unhandledRejection
[ERROR] TypeError: callback is not a function
at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/dist/AuroraDataApiDriver.js:617:29)
at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/dist/AuroraDataApiDriver.js:46:23)
at Object.throw (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/dist/AuroraDataApiDriver.js:27:53)
at rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/dist/AuroraDataApiDriver.js:19:65)
at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
at _drainQueueStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
at _drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg-aurora/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)

[Container] 2021/09/30 02:06:20 Command did not exit successfully db-migrate up exit status 1
[Container] 2021/09/30 02:06:20 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED

[Container] 2021/09/30 02:06:20 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: db-migrate up. Reason: exit status 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db-migrate` `1.0` Beta version caused the issue, downgraded to `0.11.12` resolved the issue

```
npm install --silent --no-progress -g db-migrate@0.11.12
```